# c++ hash returns different results on VS 2010 and VS 2013 with the same input

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, hash

The following command produces different results for hashed_data on 2 PCs. The one uses Visual Studio 2010 and the other Visual Studio 2013. Hash should normally give the same results with the same input

```
hash<string> hash_func;
unsigned long long hashed_data = (unsigned long long)hash_func("dogcat");
```

The computer with VS 2010 results 6824943158688951155

The computer with VS 2013 results 14899951770080783754

Other inputs produce also different results between the two PCs.

Comment: Why do you think you should get the same result?

Comment: `std::hash` is for use with hash containers, its ability to produce different hashs for the same input in different runs is a feature to prevent dos attacks.  If you want reproducibility between runs, machines and implementations, use something standardized like SHA.

Comment: The standard doesn't say how the hash should be computed, so we can expect it to be different for different implementations.

Comment: I have compiled and run this code several times and it always produces the same result on my computer. I think that is what the standard says http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/hash/

Comment: @AlexPatchanka From the documentation you linked:  *"A hash value is a value that depends solely on its argument, returning always the same value for the same argument (**for a given execution of a program**)"*. That means that different runs of the same code are allowed to produce different results here. See 17.6.3.4 Table 26 in N4140 if you care about the exact standard wording.

Comment: you are right, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It's always hard to answer a question in the negative, but the basic answer here is that multiple implementations of the Standard Library exist. Their behavior is very, very similar as far as it's documented in the Standard, but exact hash values are not documented. This leaves room for implementation optimization. Since smarter hash functions can lead to more efficient hash tables, it's to be expected that hash functions *will* differ.